# What is the advantage of loading an MLflow model as a specific flavour vs. a generic pyfunc model?

Tags: mlflow

I logged my model as an `mlflow.sklearn` model and I loaded it as a `mlflow.pyfunc` model and I am able to generate predictions. I see the same behavior when I load the model as an `mlflow.sklearn` model.

What is the advantage to loading the model as an `mlflow.sklearn` model?

The example here is specific to SKLearn but the question applies to all model flavors. Can I just load all my models from MLflow a generic Python function and use it for predictions? What are the disadvantages of that (if any)?

Comment: I think the flavors are more beneficial at the storing/saving stage, as they may relieve you from writing the custom `PythonModel`. At the inferencing stage, I'm not sure that they have any specific advantages.